# Python: Function is altering original input variable

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop, if-statement, variables

The goal is for the variable `androidApps` to be the original dataset. `androidApps1` be the dataset with missing data removed and androidApps2 to be the dataset with duplicates removed. This issue arises when I run the `removeDuplicates()` function and save it to variable `androidApps2` then dataset saved to `androidApps1` also get updated to the same dataset as `androidApps2` and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

Here I open and read my dataset file
    from csv import reader

```
openFile = open(r'C:\Users\Jason Minhas\Profitable App Profiles for the App Store and Google Play Markets\rawData\googleplaystore.csv', encoding="utf8")
readFile = reader(openFile)
androidApps = list(readFile)
```

This function checks to see if any row has a blank and returns true or false. This function is used in the next function

```
def hasBlank(row):
    for colIndex in range(0,len(row)):
        while row[colIndex] != '':
            break
        else:
            return True
    return False
```

This function finds apps with missing datapoints and returns a dataset that only has rows with all the columns filled.

```
def removeRowsWithMissingData(dataset, hasHeader=True):
    cleanDataset = []
    if hasHeader:
        start = 1
    start = 0

    for row in dataset[start:]:
        if hasBlank(row):
            pass  
        else:
            cleanDataset.append(row)

    return cleanDataset

androidApps1 = removeRowsWithMissingData(androidApps)
```

This is a function that checks for duplicates and prints the number of duplicates, uniques and total.

```
def dupeCount(dataset, index):
    UNQItems = []
    dupeItems = []
    for item in dataset:
        if item[index] in UNQItems:
            dupeItems.append(item[index])
        else:
            UNQItems.append(item[index])     
    print('Unique Apps = ' + str(len(UNQItems)))
    print('Duplicate Apps = ' + str(len(dupeItems)))
    print('Total Apps = ' + str(len(dupeItems)+len(UNQItems)))

dupeCount(androidApps1,0)
```

This function removes the duplicates and keeps the rows that have the highest review count. This function returns a clean dataset

```
def removeDuplicates(dataset, nameIndex, reviewCountIndex, hasHeader=True):
    if hasHeader:
        start = 1
    else:
        start = 0

    #create temp dataset so I dont alter orignial    
    tempDataset = dataset

    tempDataset[start:] = sorted(tempDataset[start:], key=lambda l: int(l[reviewCountIndex]), reverse=True)

    # create UNQ and dupe list
    UNQApp = []
    cleanDataset = []

    #Iterate through apps and keep only first app which will have highest review count since it's sorted.
    for row in tempDataset[start:]:
        appName = row[nameIndex]
        if appName not in UNQApp:
            UNQApp.append(appName)
            cleanDataset.append(row)

    tempDataset[start:] = cleanDataset
    return tempDataset

androidApps2 = removeDuplicates(androidApps1,0,3,hasHeader=True)

dupeCount(androidApps2,0)
```

Comment: That `hasBlank` is bizarre. Couldn't you just do `'' in row`?

Comment: `tempDataset = dataset` is not a copy.

Comment: Python does pass by reference for mutable objects. So when you call the function you are actually sending the reference to the object and not making a new list in the function. Try calling the function as removeDuplicates(androidApps1.copy(), 0, 3, hasHeader=True)

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim: Python parameter passing and variable semantics are the same for all objects, mutable or immutable. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Your link says almost exactly what I said. Look at the section titled Assignment. That's what a pass by reference does.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim no, **it absolutely does not**. Python uses a single evaluation strategy, which certainly doesn't depend on the *type of object* being passed, which is *neither* pass by reference nor pass by value. That link you are referring to **does not describe pass by reference at all**.

Comment: `tempDataset = dataset` does not create a new object. It merely assigns a new name, `tempDataset` to **the same object** being referred to by `dataset`